# WPF MenuItem display without surrounding empty area

Tags: wpf, xaml, app.xaml

In the following `XAML` I need to display the blue `rectangle` inside menu item with no grey empty area surrounding it. But as shown in the screen below, the rectangle inside menu item is showing lots of empty space surrounding the rectangle. **Question**: What I may be doing wrong here and how we can get rid of the empty space from the menu item? I've tried the using `Margin` and `StackPanel`. But no success so far. I think we probably need some sort of menu item template here. I'm following this [WPF tutorial](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/common-interface-controls/menu-control/).

**XAML**:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTESTApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTESTApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="492.182" Width="499" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel>
            <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <MenuItem Header="My Rectangle">
                    <StackPanel Width="50" Height="50">
                        <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="50" Height="50"  Margin="0,0,0,0" Stroke="Black"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
        </DockPanel>        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Screenshot of Main Window** [with design and run-time view]: In the menu item I need to display the blue rectangle only

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you need to do is to override the default control template of Menu Item . So i have taken the default control template and modified it remove the icon area from the template and applied that on the control

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuItemControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16"  SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="0"/>
                <Path x:Name="GlyphPanel" Data="F1M10,1.2L4.7,9.1 4.5,9.1 0,5.2 1.3,3.5 4.3,6.1 8.3,0 10,1.2z" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"  Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="1" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                    <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="#FF999999" BorderThickness="1"  Padding="0" Background="#FFF0F0F0" Width="Auto" >
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" Padding="0" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                            <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}"/>
                                </Canvas>
                                <Rectangle Fill="#FFD7D7D7" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Width="1"/>
                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </Popup>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#3D26A0DA"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF26A0DA"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF707070"/>
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#FF707070"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="CanContentScroll" SourceName="SubMenuScrollViewer" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

And the code for the menu item will be as given below

```
 <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" >
            <MenuItem Header="My Rectangle" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}" >

                    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="200" Height="30"   Margin="-35,0,-50,0" Stroke="Black"/>
                <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="200" Height="30"   Margin="-35,0,-50,0" Stroke="Black"/>
                </MenuItem>

        </Menu>
    </DockPanel>
```

As you can see i have applied the margin for the rectangle, it you remove that then you will be able to see padding at the left and right side.

Comment: Welcome to `Stack Overflow`. Your suggestion worked (thank you). As usual, I can access the rectangle `<Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="200" Height="30".../>` from code-behind, as well, by giving it some name, say, `x:Name = "myRectangle"`.